# ¿Como puedo hacer click con el botón derecho usando Java Script?

Tags: javascript, click

Buen dia. Me podrian ayudar a encontrar la forma de hacer click con el boton derecho del Mouse en el elemento que describo en el siguiente fragmento de codigo.

```
let b = document.getElementsByClassName('clase_elemento')[0]
b.click()
```

En este caso, el hace un click normal, pero necesito encontrar la forma para hacer un click derecho.... Gracias....

Comment: He buscado un poco acerca de esto en Google, he encontrado [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241478/how-do-i-trigger-the-browser-context-menu-on-an-element-as-if-the-user-right-c) en StackOverflow EN, donde se dice que es imposible.

Comment: Si lo que quieres es detectar cuando pulsas sobre determinado item con el click derecho debes colocar un listner al elemento (o delegar al document si quieres detectar en todo el documento) y escuchar el muoseup. Aqui te explican como: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button

Comment: Gracias Hernan Garcia, pero no es lo que quiero. Mi necesidad es hacer CLICK DERECHO sobre un elemento de una tabla, para desplegar el menu de opciones. Tal como esta el codigo, pero CLICK DERECHO

Comment: [Esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25447700/annotate-bars-with-values-on-pandas-bar-plots) podría servirte (link al sitio en inglés), he probado la respuesta aceptada pero parece estar un poco inestabe.

Answer (score 1):

Esto puede lograrlo haciendo uso del evento `contextmenu` de javascript.

```js
let b = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];
let contextmenu = document.querySelector('.container .contextMenu');
b.oncontextmenu = (evt)=>{
  evt.preventDefault(); // evitar que salga el menu del navegador
  contextmenu.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.container{
  background:#f44544;
  padding: 5px;
  position:relative;
}
.contextMenu{
  width:100px;
  height:60px;
  background: #ecf0f1;
  border:solid 2px gray; 
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
}
.contextMenu span{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Click derecho
  <div class="contextMenu">
    <span>Option 1</span>
    <span>Option 2</span>
    <span>Option 3</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

le adjunto este link por si quiere profundizar.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/contextmenu_event